# Permanent casting of void pointer at runtime

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

I'm in a situation where I don't know the type of a struct member until runtime. A file is read and the file contains information about the datatype of the struct member (it will be initialized later).

I'm wondering if there is a way to permanently cast a void pointer to another type at runtime. I was thinking the type could be indicated another way (such as storing a string that contains the type). But that introduces a lot of overhead to access the void* properly (an if statement for each potential type).

Any ideas or additional info?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "permanently"?

Comment: #define SOMETHING_I_WILL_KNOW_LATER void*; SOMETHING_I_WILL_KNOW_LATER  myStruct; when you have the information, you #undef SOMETHING_I_WILL_KNOW_LATER and redefine it with correct values.

Comment: Show your code, and we might understand exactly what you're hoping to achieve (as it's not very clear from your question), and whether or not it is possible.

Comment: In that case why even bother with a struct? Just allocate some memory and use it as you want.

Comment: You are effectively asking for the ability to recompile a chunk of your program at runtime.  Some languages have that, but C doesn't.  You *could* write a program that generated variants of your source code, though; that's an underappreciated technique.

Comment: @Yann this won't work, it will Pop up the error while redefining `i think`

Comment: @Merom : I think too, I agree that I've not try, but in C I don't see another way to "try" it :p and without information, it's the best I can do for user3734233 :).

Comment: you probably want to use a kind of generic object approach in C. You should provide some code you would like to have working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider that your file has the following format

```
offset 1: count of elements
offset 2: size of the 1st element
offset 2+1: size of 2nd element
...
offset 2+count-1: size of the last element

offset 2+count: content of 1st element
offset 2+count+size of 1st elem: content of 2nd element
...
```

And consider that you have a file with 3 elements:

```
1st elem: 
    size = 2 bytes
    content = 0x3412
2nd elem:
    size = 1 byte
    content = 0xAB
3rd elem:
    size = 5 bytes
    content = "Hell" (null terminated)
```

There follows a C program which creates such a file and then interpret it. the function `readFile` will work with any file respecting the previous described format.

Warning: this is just an example of what can be done. Note that the allocated memory is not freed, neither the I/O operations checked!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Elem{
    int size;
    void *content;
};

struct List{
    int count;
    struct Elem *elems;
};

struct List *list;

void createFile(char *name)
{
    FILE *f;
    char buf[50];
    buf[0] = 3; /* nb elems */
    buf[1] = 2; /* size of elem 1 */
    buf[2] = 1; /* size of elem 2 */
    buf[3] = 5; /* size of elem 3 */
    /* elem 1 */
    buf[4] = 0x12;
    buf[5] = 0x34;
    /* elem 2 */
    buf[6] = 0xab;
    /* elem 3 */
    buf[7] = 'H';
    buf[8] = 'e';
    buf[9] = 'l';
    buf[10] = 'l';
    buf[11] = '\0';
    f = fopen(name, "wb");
    fwrite(buf, 12, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}

void readFile(char *name)
{
    FILE *f;
    char c;
    int i;
    f = fopen(name, "rb");
    /* read number of elements */
    fread(&c, 1, 1, f);
    list->count = c;
    list->elems = (struct Elem*)malloc(sizeof(struct Elem) * c); /* allocate the needed size */
    for(i = 0; i < list->count; i++)
    {
        /* read the size of current element's size */
        fread(&c, 1, 1, f);
        list->elems[i].size = c;
        list->elems[i].content = malloc(c); /* allocate the needed size */
    }
    for(i = 0; i < list->count; i++)
    {
        /* read the current element's content */
        fread(list->elems[i].content, list->elems[i].size, 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    createFile("test");
    list = (struct List *)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    readFile("test");
    printf("elem 1: %04X\n", *((unsigned short*)list->elems[0].content));
    printf("elem 2: %02X\n", *((unsigned char*)list->elems[1].content));
    printf("elem 3: %s\n\n", (char*)list->elems[2].content);
    /* you should free the allocated memory */
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
elem 1: 3412
elem 2: AB
elem 3: Hell
```

There is how the struct is filled:

```
list -> count = 3
        elems[0]-> size = 2
                   content = 0x3412
        elems[1]-> size = 1
                   content = 0xAB
        elems[2]-> size = 5
                   content = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 0}
```

Note:

You may have noticed that the element casted to `unsigned short` saved as the sequence `{0x12, 0x34}`, has the 16 bits value `0x3421`. This is due to my computer's little endian architecture that stores the less significant bytes in lower addresses ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

Comment: +1, but you should maybe say something about endianness.

Comment: @Zack Of course! I didn't want to speak about something off-topic, but I'll add a word about it as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in C since you don't know at compile-time what the permanent cast at run-time should be.

(With C++ you could do something with static or dynamic polymorphism.)

Comment: I would say that nothing is *not possible* in C :)